# Restrict Outlook client to corporate accounts

Tags: exchange, windows-registry, group-policy

Does anyone have any experience with restricting Desktop clients of Outlook to only corporate accounts?

We have contractors who will be using our equipment and have our email, but they also require access to their mail. We want to only allow our mail in Outlook, and their mail in a browser only.

We've seen the registry key to disallow modifying accounts, is there anything else we can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a GPO that does this in the 2016 server administrative templates

Comment: It might be nice if you provided a reference to this GPO.

Comment: Outlk16.admx - Prevent Users from making changes to Outlook profiles, and Automatically configure profile based on Active Directory Primary SMTP Address